# How can I insert an empty value into a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating an array that needs to hold some empty values like this:

```
$my_array['message'] = 'hello there';
$my_array['sender'] = 'Billy Bob';
$my_array['comment'] = '';

var_dump($my_array);
```

The result of var dump is:

```
array
  'message' => 'hello there';
  'sender' => 'Billy Bob';
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
array
  'message' => 'hello there';
  'sender' => 'Billy Bob';
  'comment' => '';
```

Is it possible?

Comment: In fact that's [exactly what happens](http://ideone.com/429nh).

Comment: @Marcus As you can see, he's posted `var_dump` result.

Comment: the var_dump result also displays the comment field with a length of (0)

Comment: Strange. I was submitting some values through post and trying to var_dump($_POST) remotely and the ones with empty values weren't getting output, but locally it works fine. Must be something with the remote form handler which I didn't code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Here's a link to an example: http://codepad.org/LyPteVX6

Answer (score 0):

```
$array ['key'] = ''; // Sets an element in the array called 'key' to an empty string
```

Answer (score -1):

Var dump will skip the empty values apparently. Check with isset or == ''

Comment: var_dump will include all elements that exist, even if they contain an empty value.

Comment: my bad, thanks for correcting me! i just assumed based on the OP